# Creating string with ints in dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I know that in R, if I read in a csv file and store it in a dataframe `df` such as below

```
A B
1 2
3 4
```

I can create a vector storing values like `10_1+2` by typing

```
s<-vector()
for(i in c(1:nrow(df)) {
    r<-df[i,]
    s<-paste("10,"_",r$A,"+",r$B)
}
```

How do I something similar with Pandas in Python where I can combine int and char's into a string?

Comment: You could convert everything to the string with `df.astype(str)` and then manipulate with them as with usual strings.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you expand more on that?

Comment: Could you add your expected output after your operations?

Comment: using the example dataframe `df`, I expect to get an output of `[10_1+2, 10_3+4]` which is what it would be for a vector `s` in R and I hope it can also be for a Pandas series `s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can convert columns `A` and `B` to string by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and then concanecate them:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,3],'B': [2,4]})
print df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4

s = '10' + '_' + df['A'].astype(str) + '+' + df['B'].astype(str)
print s
0    10_1+2
1    10_3+4
dtype: object
```

If you want compare two columns `A` and `B` - it means two `Series` use condition and subset and then concanecate:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,5],'B': [2,4]})
print df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  5  4

print df.A > df.B
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool

df1 = df[df.A > df.B]
print df1
   A  B
1  5  4

s = '10' + '_' + df1['A'].astype(str) + '+' + df1['B'].astype(str)
print s
1    10_5+4
dtype: object
```

Comment: I now keep getting the error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'astype'` for the following loop:

     for index, row in df.iterrows():
         m = '10_' + row['A'].astype(str) + '+' + row['B'].astype(str)

Comment: Why do you use `iterrows()`? Because instead of `vector` you get values of vector - e.g. `int`.

Comment: so what should I use instead? I wanted to go through each row of `df` and compare the value in the `A` column with the one in the `B`

Comment: Edit answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

The data consists of integers, so those need to be converted to strings.  The data in columns `A` and `B` have been passed to the `join` function via a dereferenced `zip` operation (hence the asterisk).

```
string_int_list = ["10_" + "+".join((str(a), str(b))) 
                   for a, b in zip(*(df.A, df.B))]
>>> pd.Series(string_int_list)
0    10_1+2
1    10_3+4
dtype: object
```

Comment: I now keep getting the error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'astype'` for the following loop:

     for index, row in df.iterrows():
         m = '10_' + row['A'].astype(str) + '+' + row['B'].astype(str)

Comment: On this data, or your real data?